# Using windows functions to count by groups of dates PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table amongst whose columns are `id` and `created_at` and I want to use window functions around the `created_at` of each entry to count how many entries there are within 48 hours of them. As an example, for the original table:

```
 id | created_at
----|------------
 01 | 2016/01/04
 02 | 2016/01/05
 03 | 2016/01/05
 04 | 2016/01/06
 05 | 2016/01/07
 06 | 2016/01/08
 07 | 2016/01/08
 08 | 2016/01/09
```

and the result should be

```
 id | created_at | count
----|------------|-------
 01 | 2016/01/04 |   4
 02 | 2016/01/05 |   5
 03 | 2016/01/05 |   5
 04 | 2016/01/06 |   7
 05 | 2016/01/07 |   7
 06 | 2016/01/08 |   5
 07 | 2016/01/08 |   5
 08 | 2016/01/09 |   4
```

The explanation is that since there are 2 transactions on 2016/01/05, 1 on 2016/01/06, 1 on 2016/01/07, 2 on 2016/01/08, and 1 on 2016/01/09, there are a total of 7 transactions within 2 days of transaction 05.

Comment: Please consider describing what have you tried and what failed so people can help you

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I have no idea how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a date table that have consecutive dates in case dates in your table have gaps.
I am wondering what's the role of the id column? Here is how I would do it without considering the id column.

```
select row_number()over(order by dt) as id
,dt as created_at
,cnt1+cnt2+cnt3+cnt4+cnt5 as cnt
from
(
    select
    date_table.dt
    ,lag(cnt,2,0)over(order by created_at asc) as cnt1
    ,lag(cnt,1,0)over(order by created_at asc) as cnt2
    ,isnull(cnt,0) cnt3
    ,lead(cnt,1,0)over(order by created_at asc) as cnt4
    ,lead(cnt,2,0)over(order by created_at asc) as cnt5
    from
    date_table left join
    (select created_at,count(*) as cnt from your_table group by created_at) c
on date_table.day = c.created_at
) T
```

Comment: There are several other columns that aren't mentioned, id just identifies each row of the more interesting things.

Comment: So the other columns are not relevant? And you just want total count by day and then by plus/minus 2 day range? I tested my query with the database I work with and it works.

Comment: 48 hours, not 2 days, I edited that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using window functions for this purpose is challenging because of the duplicate days.  You can get the results using a `join` or correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2 between t.created_at - interval 2 * '1 day' and 
                         t.created_at + interval 2 * '1 day'
       ) as cnt
from t;
```

EDIT:

You could use window functions by doing a cumulative sum by date and then joining back.  This is, of course, a bit challenging because of holes in the dates.  But, something like this:

```
with c as (
      select d.dte, count(t.created_at) as cnt,
             sum(count(t.created_at))) over (order by d.dte) as cumecnt
      from (select generate_series(min(created_at) - interval '2 day', 
                                   max(created_at) + interval '2 day', 
                                   '1 day')
            from t
           ) d(dte) left join
           on d.dte = t.created_at
     )
select t.*, cmax.cumecnt - cmin.cumecnt
from t join
     c cmin
     on t.created_at = cmin.dte + interval '2 day' join
     c cmax
     on t.created_at = cmax.dte - interval '2 day';
```

Comment: The problem with that is that there are 500 thousand rows in the table, that's really slow.

Comment: You should try with an index on `created_at`.  It might not be quite as slow as you think.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "try with an index on `created_at`".

Comment: @PedroCarvalho . . . The subquery might not be so expensive if you have an index on `created_at`.

Comment: What's "an index on `created_at`" is what I mean.

Comment: `create index idx_t_created_at on t(created_at)`.

Comment: And that reduced the 500 thousand rows to 27 rows for some reason.